# @end in c-objective

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Ok, it may be a dumb mistake. But I can't figure out what xcode wants from me.

So here is the header file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "TableViewController.h"

@end
@interface Settings : NSObject

- (id)init: (TableViewController*) TableControll;

@end
```

If there is no @end before interface it says expected identifier or (, and suggests adding @end there. If there is an @end it says end must appear in objective-c contex.

Ideas?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMessageComposeViewController.h>

@interface TableViewController :     UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate>
{
    ControllerType controllerType;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray *dataArray;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray *imageArray;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil andType:(ControllerType)type;

@end
```

Comment: what is in your TableViewController.h file?

Comment: I guess an unclosed definition near the end in TableViewController.h?

Comment: I think you are missing @end in your TableViewController.h header file.

Comment: I'v added TableViewController, can't see anything wrong in it :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `@end` before the `@interface` declaration in your `Settings.h` file.

It should read:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "TableViewController.h"

@interface Settings : NSObject

- (id)init: (TableViewController*) TableControll;

@end
```

Also, you haven't included the `#import` directive for `ControllerType` in your `TableViewController.h` which may be why you're getting obscure errors in your `Settings.h` file.

Comment: If there is no @end before interface it says expected identifier or (

Comment: Check my response again. I also mentioned the `#import` directive for `ControllerType.h` if that helps?

Comment: Thanks, no problems anymore, after importing controllertype. Thank you for your help !